# Looping a python array through an excel model using openpyxl

Tags: loops, openpyxl

I have an excel property model I want to loop a series of input values through in one cell and record the output from another.

I have the following code using openpyxl to open the file in python

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook('file path')
ws = wb.active
```

and then want to iterate through a set of prices generated in python through a specific cell (C8)

```py
prices=np.arange(150000,200000,1000)
```

I then tried the following to put the output of the above through the specific cell and print in python the output from another cell, C33

```py
for x in prices:
    ws['C8']=x
    output=ws['C33']
print(output)
```

I get the following error however

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

This is the first time I have tried to loop something through excel like this, what is the best way of doing it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of your code

```
...
from openpyxl import Workbook 

wb = Workbook('file path') 
ws = wb.active
```

The 'file path' in `wb = Workbook('file path')` is invalid so `ws` is not a 'worksheet' object rather it would be a 'NoneType' object.
Later when you attempt to use `ws` in the loop you will get a Type Error like the one you've noted in your question;

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

If you are creating a new workbook and worksheet then the proper syntax is just;

```
wb = Workbook() 
ws = wb.active
```

The only valid params for `Workbook` are;
`write_only=`
`iso_dates=`
both are boolean so are either `True` or `False`

To specify the filename and path of a new workbook you do that when saving at the end, for example;
`wb.save(<path to>\<file name>)`

**However** if you meant to open an existing workbook which seems a little more likely given the rest of the code, then the syntax is;

```
...
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file path') 
ws = wb.active
```

*Where 'file path' points to a valid 'xlsx' file*

**With the loop** it's unclear to me exactly what the rest of your code is expected to do;
*and then want to iterate through a set of prices generated in python through a specific cell (C8)*

The loop will cycle through the 50 values from 150000 to 200000 in steps of 1000 assigned to 'x' and on each loop sets cell 'C8' value to 'x'. 
At the same time, assigns the variable `output` as the cell 'C33'. This means that `output` is a cell object and printing it will just display something like `<Cell 'Sheet'.C33>` on every loop. Likely you want the value of the cell instead so the line should be;
`output=ws['C33'].value`

The code could make sense if 'C33' has a formula that uses the value of 'C8' for a calculation which may be the case if you did mean to open an existing workbook. If this is your desired operation it will not work since Openpyxl does not calculate formulas. The output will be either the actual formula or the last saved value regardless of changing the value of 'C8'.
However if you were in fact wanting to create a new workbook, since there will be no data or formulas in the sheet and your code does not enter anything in cell 'C33' then it will be an empty cell.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to use win32 to open the excel file, inpuythe number and then record the number which is from another cell (which value changes based on formulas depending on the input number.